# How do you submit an ERN to the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store

When the Mac App Store says:

> To make your app available on the App Store, you must submit a copy of your U.S. Encryption Registration (ERN) approval from the U.S. Bureau of Industry (BIS).

How do you submit the ERN? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I encountered is that sometimes the upload button doesn't appear. After talking to a representative from Apple, I learned that:

> If the upload button doesn’t appear, this is what an Apple representative suggested: “If you do not see the prompt, there could be a glitch in the website. One possible workaround is to change the answer to question 4 to “Yes”. By doing this the upload field should appear.”

You can read more about my journey in getting an ERN here: [How to legally submit an app to Apple’s App Store when it uses encryption (or how to obtain an ERN)](https://carouselapps.com/2015/12/15/legally-submit-app-apples-app-store-uses-encryption-obtain-ern/)